# Space complexity of breadth first search of binary tree?

Tags: algorithm

What would be the space complexity of breadth first search on a binary tree? Since it would only store one level at a time, I don't think it would be O(n).

Comment: If a tree is balanced, it will have `~n/2` leaves so the last level will have `O(n)` size.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem - please turn that into an answer so OP can approve at will.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The space complexity is in fact `O(n)`, as witnessed by a *perfect* [binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree). Consider an example of depth four:

```
                  ____________________14____________________
                 /                                          \
         _______24_________                        __________8_________
        /                  \                      /                    \
     __27__             ____11___             ___23___              ____22___
    /      \           /         \           /        \            /         \
  _4        5        _13         _2        _17        _12        _26         _25
 /  \      / \      /   \       /  \      /   \      /   \      /   \       /   \
29   0    9   6    16    19    20   1    10    7    21    15   18    30    28    3
```

Note that the number of nodes at each depth is given by

```
depth num_nodes
0     1
1     2
2     4
3     8
4     16
```

In general, there are `2^d` nodes at depth `d`. The total number of nodes in a perfect binary tree of depth `d` is `n = 1 + 2^1 + 2^2 + ... + 2^d = 2^(d+1) - 1`. As `d` goes to infinity, `2^d/n` goes to `1/2`. So, roughly half of all nodes occur at the deepest level. Since `n/2 = O(n)`, the space complexity is linear in the number of nodes.

---

The illustration credit goes to the [binarytree](https://pypi.org/project/binarytree/) package.